# Become another user with ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have a user called `alex` that I log into the server with.  `alex` can sudo without a password.  I have another user called `jenkins` that has not password.

To manually configure something as `jenkins` I could go like this:

```
$ sudo su
# su jenkins
$ whoami
jenkins
```

or like this

```
$ sudo su jenkins
$ whoami
jenkins
```

I am trying to do something similar with Ansible 2.9.10:

```
$ virtualenv/bin/ansible -u alex -k -K example.com --become-method su --become-user jenkins -m command -a whoami
SSH password:
BECOME password[defaults to SSH password]: 
example.com | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
alex
```

```
$ virtualenv/bin/ansible -u alex -k -K example.com -b --become-method su --become-user jenkins -m command -a whoami
SSH password:
BECOME password[defaults to SSH password]: 
example.com | FAILED | rc=-1 >>
Incorrect su password
```

I have tried adding and removing `-b`, different `--become-method`... I can't get it to answer `jenkins`

There seem to be a lot of similar questions, but they are all referring to configuration files, and I was hoping to see it work like this first.

Some people suggest allowing user jenkins to log in from the outside world, but I don't think that is an option in this case.

What do I have to do?

Comment: If `jenkins` has no password, what is your exact plan to become that user from an over unprivileged account (`alex`) using using `su` ? How are you currently doing it manually on the server ?

Comment: manually I just `ssh alex@example.com` then `sudo su jenkins`

Comment: ansible is just doing `su jenkins` as your wrote it.

Comment: in my trials and errors, I also tried `--become-method 'sudo su'`.  I imagined that `-b` would mean `sudo su` and then `--become-method su --become-user jenkins` would `su jenkins` after, because manually you can also `sudo su` and then `su jenkins`

Comment: "--become-method su" doesn't necessarily has to be a problem. I receive prompt "BECOME password:" but it crashed after I typed the password "Failed to set permissions on the temporary files...". It's known problem https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/become.html#becoming-an-unprivileged-user (pipelining = true didn't help).

Comment: @Alex028502, you'll be better off with "ansible -u jenkins ..."

Comment: I am going to rewrite the question to answer all the above comments